# Passing an object as argument in function python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to pass an object clock() as an argument in function callClock()

```
class Clock():
   def initClock(self):
       doSomeStuff....

clock = Clock()
global clockFlag
clockFlag = BooleanVar()
clockFlag.set(True)

def callClock(clockFlag, obj):
   def updateClock():
       x = getattr(obj, "initClock")
       x()
   def stopClock():
    doStuffInHere...

callClock(clockFlag, clock)
```

This is for construct many clocks as wanted  and all calling the callClock function to initiate them

The working code is like this:

```
class Clock():
   def initClock(self):
       doSomeStuff....

clock = Clock()
global clockFlag
clockFlag = BooleanVar()
clockFlag.set(True)

def callClock(clockFlag):
   def updateClock():
       clock.initClock()
   def stopClock():
    doStuffInHere...

callClock(clockFlag)
```

But I'm trying to reuse the callClock function to every new Clock that is created, not only for the clock.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your code looks like you have to repeat the tutorial on classes in Python.

Comment: @KlausD. hahahaha yeah, I know xD